# Can we assign a new propagator different from domain and bounds in GECODE solver for solving linear constraints?

Tags: algorithm, propagation, gecode

Linear equations/inequations can be easily solved by simplex algorithm which is very fast. But for GECODE solver we only have two propagators : domain and bounds which solve the constraints that have different approach for solving linear problems and have time complexity near to NP Hard. \n
Can we modify the GECODE solver code to assign a new propagator that will use the simplex algorithm for solving linear constraints? Any idea?